# How do I set multiple values in a Javascript Map at once?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, getter-setter

I have a simple chain of logic here, where bigCities is a Javascript Map. In this example, d represents each object in an array of data read in from a csv file. For every object's city property, I'm assigning it's d.pop value (the population of the city).

`bigCities.set(d.city, +d.pop)`

What if I want to be able to set multiple values at once? Would the code look something like this:

```
bigCities.set(d.city, ["population": +d.pop, "latitude": +d.lat, "longtitude": +d.lng)
```

Is it possible to create a key value pair in a Javascript Map, where the value is an array of data? If so, how would I write the above example correctly?

Comment: Sure you could have an array as the value of a `Map` entry, but your syntax is messed up. Is that supposed to be an integer-indexed array or a string-keyed object?

Comment: Change to: `bigCities.set(d.city, {"population": +d.pop, "latitude": +d.lat, "longtitude": +d.lng});`  That will make the key be the city name and the value will be an object with three properties on it.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To set multiple keys and values at a `Map` object you can pass an array of arrays

```js
let m = new Map([["a", [1,2,3]], ["b", [4,5,6]]]);

console.log([...m], m.get("a"))
```

Comment: @le_m Or `Object.values(d).forEach(({city, pop:population, lat:latitude, lng:longitude}) => bigCities.set(city, {population, latitude, longitude}))`

Comment: ah, I misinterpreted "multiple values" as "multiple entries". Of course associating keys with arrays as you did is a proper solution.

Comment: Similarly it works for sets as well. newSet = new Set([1,2,3])

Comment: @PaulPacurar What do you mean by "does not work"? The code in the answer passes one  (1) `Array` to the constructor.

Comment: I had some issues with the types I used inside. deleted previous comment since I was wrong, thanks

Answer (score 5):

```js
const map = new Map();

map.set("a", "alpha").set("b", "beta").set("c", "charlie");

console.info(map); // Map(3) {'a' => 'alpha', 'b' => 'beta', 'c' => 'charlie'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to populate the map with the array entries:

```
const map = ['one', 'two', 'three']
  .reduce((acc, item, idx) => acc.set(idx, item), new Map());

// gives:
// > Map(3) {0 => 'one', 1 => 'two', 2 => 'three'}
```

or if array values are objects:

```
const mapObjects = [
  {id: 'ny', city: 'New York', population: 123}, 
  {id: 'waw', city: 'Warsaw', population: 321}
].reduce((acc, item) => acc.set(item.id, item), new Map());

// gives:
// > Map(2) {'ny' => {…}, 'waw' => {…}}
```

you can even update items of an existing map

```
const map = ['one', 'two', 'three']
  .reduce((acc, item, idx) => acc.set(idx, item), new Map());

['newOne', 'newTwo']
  .reduce((acc, item, idx) => acc.set(idx, item), map); // updates "map" in place, no need to capture return value

//gives:
// > Map(3) {0 => 'newOne', 1 => 'newTwo', 2 => 'three'}
```

#### What's happening?

You pass `new Map()` as the accumulator, then for each item of the array you set the value for given key in the acc, finally `acc.set` returns the map itself as the new value of accumulator. In other words it works like method chaining:

```
new Map().set(0, 'one').set(1, 'two').set(2, 'three');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is an object that has three properties on it.  You can make the city the key and an object like that be the value in the `Map` by setting it like this:

```
bigCities.set(d.city, {"population": +d.pop, "latitude": +d.lat, "longitude": +d.lng});
```

Then, to read it back again, you'd do this:

```
let info = bigCities.get(d.city);
console.log(info.population);
console.log(info.latitude);
console.log(info.longitude);
```

---

Hopefully, you recognize the syntax:

```
{"population": +d.pop, "latitude": +d.lat, "longitude": +d.lng}
```

as a Javascript literal object declaration.  This creates a Javascript object with three property/value pairs where you reference the property by name.